# Maintain list of apliances, devices, and gadgets

Tags: cross-platform, inventory

I'm looking for a simple free piece of software that has a nice GUI to keep a list of, for example:

- devices,
- their serial numbers,
- purchase dates,
- warranty periods,
- owner's comments.

It should be free, preferably FOSS. Also, it would be great to have clients for Windows, Linux, Android and some kind of synchronization between them.

Of course, I can write this info into a text file, but that't not fancy. A business inventory system will be to much.

Answer (score 1):

How about a kanban board? The Kanban method was primarily developed to make the material / goods flow in production visible.

There are numerous Kanban tools, most of them also have a free plan. I use [Trello](https://trello.com/) in many projects. Trello can be used via browser and mobile apps.

We have already used Kanban for a sporting goods manufacturer for product management. Worked out great. Here we had different columns for the different categories. In each column there were cards for each product. On the cards we noted all kinds of things (suppliers, prices, quantities, comments...).

For the real numbers (how much of each product is in stock) we had a separate system.